# Date-time always giving 1200HRS

Tags: python, dialogflow-es

I'm working on a chatbot and using Dialogflow's sys.date-time entity. So when I'm presenting some dates to the bot, like "Today", or "Feb 14", I always get

```
"parameters": {
  "date-time": "2021-02-14T12:00:00Z"
}
```

whereas I want

```
"parameters": {
  "date-time": "2021-02-14T00:00:00Z"
}
```

Right now I'm using my app to replace the `datetime` with `hours=0`, however, I also want the bot to give

```
"parameters": {
  "date-time": "2021-02-14T08:00:00Z"
}
```

when I say "feb 14 8AM" (hour is explictly mentioned), but the app will replace the hours. So gonna have to fix it from Dialogflow side. Any solutions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this semantic bug by properly analysing the `value` received for `@sys.date-time` built-in entity of Dialogflow with multiple phrases.

When just a day/date is mentioned (say `Feb 14 2020`), this is the data I receive:

```
"parameters": {
  "date-time": "2020-02-14T12:00:00Z"
}
```

When I mention time along with the date **explicitly** (say `Feb 14 3pm`), this is the data received:

```
"parameters": {
  "date-time": {
    "date_time": "2021-02-14T15:00:00Z"
  }
}
```

The difference here is that in the second case, a nested dictionary is presented in `date-time`.

Distinguishing between that, I was able to slice the ISO-8601 format on my app and replace `12:00:00` with `00:00:00`, but if I received a dictionary instead, I did not slice/replace it.

Answer (score 1):

for Dialogflow system entity `@sys.date-time` this is the default behavior as per ISO-8601 format , what you can do as the fix for this is to instead of using `@sys.date-time` follow these steps :

1. use two separate parameters for date and time `@sys.date` and `@sys.time`.
2. Make `@sys.date` as required and `@sys.time` as optional.
3. Set some appropriate default value for `@sys.time` as `00:00:00` so when time is not given like FEB 14 it will take time as default value .
4. In your app you can use these two values .

**Sample intent**

[image]

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thank you. Is there anyway I could just get the date part from the 'date' parameter instead of all of it and set default value of "that date's date"? (Is slicing is the only option?) I will also use phrases like "Between tuesday 9am and friday 11pm", will that work with it?

Comment: I think you have to do slicing at your app level though somehow  dialogflow give in its response only date and time  but its sends whole date time object as json request to webhook , for this one `Between tuesday 9am and friday 11pm` you can make extra parameter ex. date1 or time1 as per your logic . Please accept the answer and upvote :)